# Submitting data to form and interacting with website, automation

Tags: java, forms, web

Suppose I have a website that I can log into (at any time) and submit data to every x hours (click a link visible once logged in), how would I go about automating this process?

I have built a gui that provides the user (for now me, for my own convenience) an interface with some information, lets the user type in the log-in info and a button for starting a scheduled and repeated task in a `ScheduledExecutorService` but I am stuck at that point. Currently I use the `Desktop` api and `browse()` and rely on the user having logged in and just browse the url of the clickable link.

Knowing the URL of the loginsite, how do I submit the login info from my application to the the loginform of the website and let the website process it? (and let my app know the login was sucessful) and then click the link that will be visibile at a different URL once the login succeeds?

Comment: is the website developed by you or a third party project?

Comment: It is my own website, there are probably better ways of transferring data but I wanted to learn this. Further research made me stumble upon https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/GettingStarted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need [Web Services](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gijti.html). Try exploring [WSDL](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giqsx.html#gkcdg) or [REST](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giqsx.html#gkcaw) [api](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbji.html).

**EDIT :** Looks like you are trying to use Selenium which is a functional test framework. Set it up like the program describes at the end of the getting started page. After that you should be able to access the html page elements as provided in the [tutorial](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/NextSteps#Interacting_With_the_Page).

Answer (score 1):

If the webapp doesn't expose some kind of web service you cannot automate login procedure or any other action on the site.

If the website is your project, than you can implement web methods that allow you to achieve what you need.